# Adding a geojsonlayer for react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, geojson, gtfs

I have some geojson data that I have created from a gtfs realtime feed, I am trying to add it to a mapbox map. My Map currently displays fine and I can get it to render markers, however I am having issues with rendering geojson data.

```
<div>
     <Map
         style="mapbox://styles/.../cjw2k3na404qn1csfznqo90z7"
         containerStyle={{ width: '85vw', height: '90vh'}}
         center={this.props.center}>
                <GeoJSONLayer ...../> 
     </Map>
```

I do not know what should be entered in the `<GeoJSONLayer />` tag which is being imported as `import { GeoJSONLayer, ... , ... } from "react-mapbox-gl"`.

Comment: No Errors result from this code and the geojson data i have is indeed populated, I have tried adding in singular points inside the geojson tag but with no luck